# possibility of using several virtual environments simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x

hello I noticed that some of the libraries I use are used for development but also for analysis and sometimes I have to use both is there a way to use a basic virtual environment as in the templates and can I use the two libraries a few times simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

- Create two virtual environments.
- Call them v1 and v2
- Open terminal x 2
- First terminal - activate v1 and install your library 1
- Second terminal - activate v2 and install your library 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use multiple virtual environments. You need to create virtual envs. If you're already aware of anaconda env, you can create virtual envs with them else you can go in the normal way of creating venvs.

After creating them, have 2 terminals each for each venv. Run your scripts.